Output process of Huffman encoding an i.i.d. source
A binary Huffman code for a pmf $(p_1,\dots,p_m)$ is constructed by starting with all $p_i$ as leaves and iteratively constructing a tree by merging the two nodes of lowest probability. Edges are then given labels in $\{0,1\}$, and we read off codewords by the root-leaf paths.
I've been trying to see what kind of structure we can guarantee on the stream of bits Huffman coding produces - when viewed as a stochastic process.
Formally, let $(X_i)_{i\ge 0}$ be an i.i.d. source and $(Z_i)_{i\ge 0}$ be the sequence of bits we get from encoding each $X_i$ and concatenating their encodings. Huffman codes are designed to be prefix codes, so this stream is a well-defined way of transmitting the $X_i$.
In general, it seems like we can't expect $(Z_i)_{i\ge 0}$ to be a Markov chain. The Huffman code for $\{A,B,C\}$ on pmf $\{0.4,0.3,0.3\}$ is $\{0,10,11\}$; observing $01$ in the output stream guarantees we are in the middle of a $10$ or $11$, so we have a $0.5$ probability of observing $1$ next. However, observing $11$ we are either about to start a new codeword - probability $0.6$ of observing a $1$ - or halfway through a $10$ - no chance of getting a $1$. We need to multiply $0.6$ by the probability of being in that first scenario, which I am struggling to do, but this feels like it should come out to not be $0.5$.
Further to my struggles on that particular calculation, it feels like if the pmf were to be changed to $\{0.5,0.25,0.25\}$ we do get an equal split of probabilities - as note the $0.6$ in the latter case above becomes $0.5$. Any dyadic pmf I've tried seems to also give clean splits - which has me wondering whether it's possible we actually do get a Markov chain in this case?
Any clarification on what's going on here and whether I'm going down the right lines would be great. I will point out I very well might be calculating incorrectly in the first case and we could in fact always get a Markov chain - though this seems unlikely to me.
